# No such module 'ModuleName' error when using CocoaPods without 'use_frameworks!' option

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I want to stop using `use_frameworks!` so my dependencies are linked statically. As I know, one way to solve `No such module 'ModuleName'` error in this case is to add `use_modular_headers!` in Podfile.

The problem is that `use_modular_headers!` brings another error. Is there a way to avoid both `use_frameworks!` and `use_modular_headers!`?

- CocoaPods: 1.5.3
- Xcode: 10.1
- Swift: 4.0

Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

plugin 'cocoapods-fix-react-native'

platform :ios, '11.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

pod 'RxSwift'
pod 'RxCocoa'

target 'AppName' do
  pod 'RxDataSources'
  pod 'R.swift'
  pod 'Kingfisher'
  pod 'KDEAudioPlayer', :git => 'https://github.com/delannoyk/AudioPlayer.git', :branch => 'master'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'VIMVideoPlayer'
  pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
  pod 'React', :podspec => '../../react/external/React.0.54.4.podspec.json', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'cxxreact',
    'DevSupport',
    'fishhook',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTWebSocket',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTSettings',
    # Contains deprecated UIKit stuff...
    # 'RCTPushNotification',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTBlob',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'ART',
    'PrivateDatabase',
    'jsinspector',
    'jschelpers',
    'CxxBridge'
  ]
  pod 'yoga', :podspec => '../../react/external/yoga.0.54.4.podspec.json'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../react/node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../react/node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'react-native-video', :path => '../react/node_modules/react-native-video/react-native-video.podspec'

end
```

Answer (score 1):

The CocoaPods 1.6.0 pre-release may fix the problem with `use_modular_headers!`.

If not and you can provide enough information to reproduce, please file a [CocoaPods issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution even it's doesn't look to good/scalable.

Instead of using `use_modular_headers!` option we can import classes we using via `BridgingHeader`. What you need to do is to add `BridgingHeader.h` file in your Swift project an import all the headers you need. The file will look like this:

```
// These are imported manually to avoid using 'use_modular_headers!' option in Podfile.
// 'use_modular_headers!' leads to error with 'glog' dependency.
import <VIMVideoPlayer/VIMVideoPlayer.h>
import <VIMVideoPlayer/VIMVideoPlayerView.h>
import <React/RCTBridge.h>
import <React/RCTRootView.h>
import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
```